# How to inform background task if the foreground app is terminated?

Tags: silverlight, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

Using Windows phone 8.1 silverlight 
Background Task is a WinRT Task.

The problem I'm facing is I'm running a background task and I want the background task to exit when the foreground App is closed or terminated.
I know when closing the foreground App I can use the Application_closing method to write to isolated storage to communicate with the background task. 
But the real question is how do I handle the event when the foreground App goes from suspension state to terminated state. Or even if is it possible for the background task to query the status of the foreground App to the OS.
Thanks you.

Comment: What type of background task are you writing, and when exactly do you need it to shutdown (suspension, losing foreground status, termination)?

Comment: @Peter I'm trying to schedule a toast notification at a certain time in the background but I don't want the toast notification when the foreground App is closed or terminated. Hence I would like to un-schedule it if the App is terminated.

Comment: In previous releases, Windows Phone would suppress toasts if the app was in the foreground... not sure if that still happens or not. Anyway, one way you could figure this out is with named events - see [this article and associated code](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/03/27/using-named-events-to-coordinate-foreground-apps-and-background-agents/)

Comment: What is the purpose in differentiating between suspended and terminated state of your app?  In both cases your foreground code is not running so what's the benefit in knowing this?

Comment: @Jimmy Alexander : Well for a programmer we know the app is suspended but as a end user will always think the app is still running. In my case its like a simple countdown timer if the app is suspended I still want to send him a notification when the timer hits 0. But don't want to do this if the app is terminated.

Comment: @AbsoluteSith : You want to do different things (send notification on suspended but not on terminated) based on something as you say the user cannot differentiate (suspension vs termination).  That sounds like a non ideal user experience.  You application behavior should tailor to the user expectations not on the application lifecycle state which is an implementation detail that is irrelevant to your user.  To do a notification on timer that will work on suspended or terminated pass that action onto the OS.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202946(v=vs.105).aspx.

Comment: @Jimmy Alexander : Yep that's the only way to go. I'm scheduling a notification as soon as the timer starts. But imagine yourself to be the user using a simple countdown timer app do you still want to get the notification/reminder if you terminate(not close) the app. As most of the time users first suspend the App and later realize they don't need the app and then terminate with a long press of back-key. So giving them a notification even when they close the App is somewhat a bad experience.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to get information about your app going from the suspended into the terminated state. That's why most articles on MSDN explicitely state that you have to save any session related data before an app is suspended.

> You should always save user information and app data in the suspending event because Windows doesn’t notify apps before it terminates them. This is important because termination can occur under a variety of circumstances, such as when Windows needs to free memory or the device loses (battery) power.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj660301.aspx

What you *could* do is to implement some kind of ping mechanism where your foregound app constantly writes timestamps to the isolated storage. If these 
pings exceed a predefined timestamp you can assume your app was terminated and exit the background task.

Comment: But then my foreground App wouldn't be able to ping if its in a suspended state? and I want to send the notification if the App is suspended/running but not when its closed/terminated.

Comment: You should have a second flag in the isolated storage that indicates if your app is running or suspended (I thought you had that already). The important point is: You cannot explicitely tell if your app has been suspended or terminated. But: If you only have a running flag in your store but no ping you can be pretty sure the user has terminated the app. And if you have a suspended flag and no ping for two hours you can also assume you app is terminated. It's all based on assumptions and you have to tune your system wisely.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I guess they're is no sure shot way of knowing the state of the app. I think this a important feature and MS should have incorporated it.